# Is it generally possible to spend 2 years on a 1-year integrated master's program in the UK?

Tags: masters, united-kingdom

I am about to begin an integrated master's (MSc) program at a UK university (in STEM major). The course is very short (9 months), but the lectures/materials are very intense. I want to pursue a PhD at the same university after this program, but I think it would be hard if I want to get familiar with a professor in such a short period of time and ask for a reference letter.

I wonder generally, is it possible to delay a year to graduate in the UK? Can I spend an extra year on this program? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you asked the course leader or the course admin team? What did they say?

Comment: @Dmitry Savostyanov I just emailed them and waiting for the response. I was trying to find out if anyone have a similar experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, UK universities allow students to defer their studies. Typically, though, it happens for undergraduate courses that span several years.

Rather then deferring, you may consider taking the course part-time. This is often a preferred option for a University from the admin point of view. Effectively, you will take half of the modules each term and then progress to the dissertation. This may be impossible if the second-semester modules all require all first-semester modules as prerequisites, but this is very rarely a case.

Your course admin team may be able to give a better advice. Ask them.

Comment: Thanks so much!!